# Need to enable focus on <ui:inputTextArea /> lightning component field

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I am using a button to open a modal and inside a modal there is some form fields and I when user a modal then `<ui:inputTextArea />` should be automatically on focus mode so a user can directly start typing without on click in field.

Codes..
A Application event fire by another component and i am using following function to open modals according to value.
**handleEvent** controller fire by a event

**Component and controller from whare we calling event**

```
 <lightning:button aura:id="logacall" label="Log A Call" value="1" onclick="{!c.openModal }" />


openModal: function(component, event){
    var menuValue = event.getSource().get("v.value");

    // Fire lightning event to call related modal        
 var DI_ActionEvent = $A.get("e.c:DealInvestors_ActionEvent");
            DI_ActionEvent.setParams({
                modalId: menuValue
            });
            DI_ActionEvent.fire();  
    },
```

**Component**

```
<aura:handler event="c:DealInvestors_ActionEvent" action="{!c.handleEvent}"/>

 <div class="slds-form-element__control">
     <ui:inputTextArea aura:id="formTextArea" />
 </div>
```

**Controller**

```
handleEvent : function(component, event, helper) {
    var modalId = event.getParam("modalId");

    switch(modalId) {
        case "1": helper.logCall(component); break;
        case "2": helper.logEmail(component); break;
        case "3": helper.addNote(component); break;
        case "4": helper.blackList(component); break;
        case "5": helper.scheduleTask(component); break;
    }
```

**In Helper**

```
logCall : function(component) {
    var cmpTarget = component.find('ActionModalBack');
    var cmpBack = component.find('ADM-Back');
    $A.util.addClass(cmpTarget, 'slds-fade-in-open');
    $A.util.addClass(cmpBack, 'slds-backdrop--open'); 
    component.set("{!v.getTitle}", 'Log A Call');

    component.find("formTextArea").getElement().focus();

},
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add an `aura:id` to your input like this:

```
<ui:inputTextArea aura:id="my-element" />
```

Then, when the modal is displayed, select your input in your javascript function, and set the focus to it:

```
component.find("my-element").getElement().focus();
```

Comment: Its not working for me...

Comment: When i am using setTimeout function with 5 second this will start working.  Why ?? i don't want to use any timeout

Comment: This is because you have to execute this code when the modal fire the is shown event (ie: when the modal finished its loading). Please post your whole javascript code about the modal.

Comment: Code updated please check what is the issue..

Comment: Where's the part of the modal show event?

Comment: I am using a component and inside this component there is button and once user click a button we send a value using event call the another component to open modal.... Code updated

Comment: It seems that the class `slds-fade-in-open` starts an animation on the modal. And I don't find any way to know when the animation ends by using the lightning design system yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60707/discussion-between-tariq-and-martin-lezer).

Answer (score 2):

> It's working by adding a small timeout

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
  component.find("my-element").getElement().focus();
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try ensuring your component is version is 40, and using the lightning:input type="textarea" and then cmp's api focus method.

```
 component.find('myinput').focus();
```